# Op-amp first-order low-pass filters, capacitor placement in inverting circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, active-filter

In the picture below the *lag circuits at the input decide cutoff frequency* by making the input voltage at the op-amp vanish at frequencies much higher than the cut-off frequency.

I understand the first two circuits.
However, in the third circuit, I don't get why the capacitor was shifted to the feedback path. I see that at high frequencies this capacitor makes the feedback resistance 0, which makes gain = 0.

Why can't we put the lag circuit at the input (like in the first two circuits) in the third circuit? Will it not work? Why are we placing the capacitor in the feedback path and making the gain 0? Why can't we simply make the input 0 instead?

[image]

Comment: Please explain exactly where you would consider placing the capacitor in the third picture.

Comment: @Andyaka I was expecting to see a voltage divider at the negative input of opamp. Just like in the first two circuits. But I think i know why you ask -  the negative input is virtual ground since the positive input is grounded... Is this the reason?

Comment: @across no, the reason is "draw a picture of how you imagine it"

Comment: @Ilya like this here https://prnt.sc/OFFfwGECcGyo

Comment: @Andyaka omg! so in a basic inverting opamp, the negative input "doesn't see" the full input signal. Some part of the input is lost across input R1  resistor. This R1 resistor seems to act as the source resistance of a high impedance driver! the input signal that the opamp sees is just the part that gets dropped across the feedback resistor. not sure if im making sense..

Answer (score 2):

> *@Andyaka I was expecting to see a voltage divider at the negative
> input of opamp.*

[image]

That won't work; the capacitor will be basically doing nothing other than generating some high-frequency noise. This is because the -V input is a virtual ground point and, isn't a suitable place to filter the incoming input signal on an inverting amplifier.

> *@Andyaka omg! so in a basic inverting opamp, the negative input
> "doesn't see" the full input signal. Some part of the input is lost
> across input R1 resistor.*

The op-amp seeks to keep -Vin at the same voltage as +Vin hence -Vin is called a virtual ground. It does this because of the negative feedback and, think about it; if there was a significant voltage difference between -Vin and +Vin the output would be banged-up against one of the power rails because, the gain of an op-amp is massive (range 100,000 to 1,000,000 typically).

So, the input voltage gets converted to a current that flows through R1 to virtual ground (0 volts). It's 0 volts because +Vin is at 0 volts.

Then, that same current flows through the feedback resistor (R2). That current x R2 equals the negative of the output voltage. All of Vin has to be across R1. Hence the voltage across R2 is R2/R1 times bigger in magnitude compared to Vin. That's how an inverting op-amp works.